# How to connect 2 nodes of a same shape with connector lines in VBA PPT?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to connect to nodes of a shape with a connector line and this is my code, could anyone help with this.

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.AddConnector(Type:=msoConnectorStraight, BeginX:=0, _
        BeginY:=0, EndX:=100, EndY:=100).ConnectorFormat

    .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=Shp, ConnectionSite:=3
    .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=Shp, ConnectionSite:=1        
    .Parent.RerouteConnections

End With
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?  Please clarify

Comment: Im trying to connect two nodes of a same shape with a straight connector using the above code, by setting the connectionSite values, however it is not working

Comment: Can you please explain more fully what 'doesn't work' means?  What does it do?

Comment: can you do the connection manually?

Comment: Jsotola, yes I can connect the nodes manually

Comment: @LordWilmore: now this code creates a connector from and to a same node of same shape, the node on the top right corner. I want to connect top left corner node and top right corner node.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `ConntectedShape` refers to different shapes or is it a typo here?

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.AddConnector(Type:=msoConnectorStraight, _
        BeginX:=0, BeginY:=0, EndX:=100, EndY:=100).ConnectorFormat
    .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=Shp, ConnectionSite:=3 ' <-- Shp1?
    .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=Shp, ConnectionSite:=1 ' <-- Shp2?
    .Parent.RerouteConnections
End With
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thats the question case here. I want to connect 2 nodes of same shape using a connector.